# how to implement custom grouping in jqGrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I'm starter in jqGrid, i write this code for Implement Grouping

```
$(function () {
            var mydata = [
                          { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                          { id: "12", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "13", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                          { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                          { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                          { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" }, 
                          { id: "18", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "19", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                          { id: "21", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                          { id: "22", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "23", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }, 
                          { id: "24", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                          { id: "25", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "26", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                          { id: "27", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                          { id: "28", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                          { id: "29", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00"}];
            jQuery("#list48").jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: "local",
                height: 'auto',
                rowNum: 30,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date", formatter: "date" },
                    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number", editable: true },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", editable: true },
                    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false}],
                pager: "#plist48",
                viewrecords: true,
                sortname: 'name',
                grouping: true,
                groupingView: { groupField: ['name'] },
                caption: "Grouping Array Data" });

        });
```

and create this grid
[image]

i want set Grouping Dynamicaly.Such that user Drag Header Column and Drop in top box after that grid Grop such this picture
[image]
please help me for implement this senaryo
. thanks all

Comment: Do you know how to implement the UI part of drag and drop and only the jqGrid part is the issue or you have completly no idea on how to do any part of the functionality?

Comment: @ tpeczek: i don't have idea for any part. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the jqGrid side you need to use `groupingRemove` and `groupingGroupBy` methods to change grouping dynamic, you can read more about them in [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping).

For the UI part you should look at following interactions:

- [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)
- [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)
- [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

The *Shopping Cart* sample in **Droppable** should give you a very good overview on how to approach the subject.

Now after all that theoretical informations, I have created a sample on jsFiddle for you: [jqGrid dynamic drag-n-drop grouping](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/vRtKS/). It needs some styling to look exactly as what you are looking for, but it should allow you to understand all the internals. If you need some comments on the code let me know - I can add them later.

Comment: @ tpeczek: thanks for help me, @tpeczek i have another problem in jqgrid and i ask question about this problem in this topic please help me. thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556375/how-to-hide-cloumn-in-jqgrid-in-asp-net

Comment: @M.B Well that question is a little bit unclear, I think you should rephrase it and describe in more details so we can take a closer look.

Comment: @ tpeczek: i change text Question please see this question again. thanks