# Does jqGrid support builtin dynamic drag-n-drop columns grouping header?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm wondering if the latest jqGrid version contains built-in dynamic drag-n-drop column grouping header.  Or do i have to write one from scratch?

I saw few postings about it but they're over 1 years old and a lot had changed since then.  Here's the links below to see what I'm trying to say.

[how to implement custom grouping in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565174/how-to-implement-custom-grouping-in-jqgrid)

http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/vRtKS/

```
//Ignore this script below - Stackoverflow required me to post code/scripts but it's contained in other links.
$('#Spreadsheet')...
```

We're junking the GridEx.

Thanks...

Comment: The example scripts in jsfiddle.net does not work w/ jqGrid 4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know Jqgrid only support drag and drop sortable columns that use Sortable option. You need to make custom function to make it work.
If you want to use drag and drop grouping column, I recommend you use KendoUI (Telerik Component).They have a free edition.

Comment: Okay, I'll go along w/ your suggestion on making custom function for it to work.  I could use some help along the way (in seperate posting).  :-)  I also filed a bug report at <https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/459> .

Comment: Refiled bug report at https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/issues/8 .   Tony Tomov now no longer allow jqGrid to be free and it required a purchased license.  So, I stopped using Tony's jqGrid & start following Oleg's jqGrid.